# "This express is not callable. Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures"

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I'm trying to create a React component using typescript but I got this error in my console "This expression is not callable. Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures."

Sandbox link for my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-carson-16lpe?file=/src/App.tsx

The error seems to be coming from line 17 for the 'setOpenPopup' props.

Not sure what I can do to correct the error. Would appreciate any help to troubleshoot. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interface is wrong. By convention, setOpenPopup should be a function that takes a boolean and return any value most likely void

```
interface PopupProps {
    openPopup: boolean;
    setOpenPopup: (open: boolean) => void;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of the prop is a boolean, however, in the component it is being called as a function. I believe you want

```
setOpenPopup: (isOpen: boolean) => void; // signature of a function which accepts a boolean
```

Comment: passing boolean as a variable is a bad practice. boolean is a type name and is confusing to understand. Use a variable that is more contextual

Comment: Yes, I made a typo. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

I had this error because I was doing a stupid mistake that I was using a `setter` method as a regular method.
My mistake was:
`spot.setIsOccupied(occupiedValue);`
The correct way is:
`spot.setIsOccupied = occupiedValue;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Dispatch` and `SetStateAction` which should be imported from `react`

```
import { Dispatch, setStateAction } from 'react'

interface PopupProps {
    openPopup: boolean;
    setOpenPopup: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}
```